# Zeros of Multivariate Complex Functions [need reference]

Tags: reference-request, cv.complex-variables

I am looking for a good accessible reference that would summarize properties of zeros of complex analytic functions.

For my purpose, it would be interesting to see a discussion  on the following topics:

1. Zeros of single variable analytic function are discrete (isolated)
2. Zeros of multivariable analytic functions are not isolated
3. The set of zeros of an analytic function of $n$ variables roughly speaking lives in $n-1$ dimensional space.

I have been reading "Functional Theorem of Several Complex Variables"  by Krantz.   While I found the book interesting to read, I don't think that it is very accessible to a non-mathematician.  Right now looking for a reference that would be more accessible to a senior Ph.D. student in engineering with a good background in single variable complex analysis.  In any case, any reference on this subject that you can provide would be of great help to me.

Comment: It sounds like you want references for the Weierstrass Preparation Theorem. The article https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_preparation_theorem seems helpful. You could also try the references listed at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MR1111477 Chirka, E. M. Complex analytic sets. Kluwer Academic Publishers Group, Dordrecht, 1989.

Comment: In this book Chapter 1 devoted to zeros of analytic functions. However, I couldn't find any reference to the dimensionality of a set of zeros.   Can you point me to the correct chapter or theorem?